# Finding $\sqrt{17}$ and $\sqrt{257}$ in the regular $17$-gon and $257$-gon?

Tags: radicals, polygons, geometric-construction, roots-of-unity

(***Edit***: *I need to revise this question with my original intent. Pls do not answer it yet. Thanks*.)

---

Given the regular $n$-gon formed by the $n$-th roots of unity. For some $n$, how do we find $\sqrt{n}$ using the sum/difference of ***line segments***?

> $n=5:$

It is enough to use ***one*** line segment: If $x^5=1$, then it can be the distance  between the root $x_0$ on the real line, and $x_2$ in the second quadrant,

$\hskip2.2in$ [image]

$$1+\sqrt{\big(1+\cos\big(\tfrac{4\pi}{5}\big)\big)^2+\big(\sin\big(\tfrac{4\pi}{5}\big)\big)^2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\tag1$$

> $n=17:$

I observed that using the sum/difference of ***four*** line segments would do. Define,

$$L(\alpha,\beta)=\sqrt{\left(\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi\,\alpha}{17}\big)+\cos\big(\tfrac{2\pi \,\beta}{17}\big)\right)^2+\left(\sin\big(\tfrac{2\pi\,\alpha}{17}\big)-\sin\big(\tfrac{2\pi \,\beta}{17}\big)\right)^2}$$

then,

$$L(0,3)-L(1,5)+L(3,7)+L(4,8)=\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{2}\tag2$$

> $n=257:$

$$???\tag3$$

**Questions:**

1. Is there an alternative to $(2)$ that is purely a sum of *positive* values?
2. How do we find $(3)$? (I assume it needs $64$ line segments.)

Comment: So to find $(a+b\sqrt{n})/c$ for some integers $a,b,c$ is enough?

Comment: Yes. Minor tweaking can then isolate $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @ccorn: Thanks for $n=5$. I've also revised $n=17$ since the distance formula must take into account if points are in different quadrants.

Comment: Deleting my answer till the dust has settled.

Comment: Why the initial $1+$ in formula (1)? Without it, it looks like usual distance formula, and gives $(1+\sqrt{5})/2.$

Comment: @coffeemath: the squareroot in $(1)$ yields $(\sqrt{5}-1)/2$. The initial $1+$ was for consistency with earlier versions of $(2)$, cf. the [edit history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1646385/revisions). The actual problem (at least description-wise) is the $1+$ within the squareroot, as that suggests a distance to $-1$ rather than $+1$.

Comment: @ccorn: I'm deleting this question temporarily because the way I phrased it didn't capture my intent.

Comment: How is the revision coming along?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I totally forgot about this. I'll have to go over some old notes...

Answer (score 6):

If $p\equiv1\bmod4$, then $\sum_0^{p-1}e^{2\pi ia^2/p}=\sqrt p$.

And if $p≡3$ mod $4$ the right side of the sum equality is just $i\sqrt{p}$. Such sums, for either caae, are called Gauss sums.

For example in a regular hendecagon with vertices numbered 0 through 10 in rotational order, the Gauss sum shows that the distances from vertex $k$ to $11−k$, with $k$ nonzero and a negative sign attached for $k=2$, gives $\sqrt{11}$ times the circumradius.

Comment: Gerry: My apologies, but I asked that my question to be temporarily closed until I clarify some things.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Closing does not give you a fool-proof peace. Some eager beavers may reopen it! I could close and lock it, but then you couldn't edit the question either. Why don't you write some kind of a statement about your intent on the first line of the post, and remove that when you are done editing. That would be simpler. Not guaranteed to work, but nothing is.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, Tito, a line segment is just a difference of two roots of unity.